# Left merge two dataframes and fill only NaN values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For dataframes `df1` and `df2`, I want to left merge them based on `date` to get `df`, if `v1` or `v2` has values, then take them, otherwise take the values from `df2`.

**df1**

```
      date    v1    v2
0  2017-01  12.0   1.0
1  2017-02   2.0  13.0
2  2017-03  15.0   3.0
3  2017-04   NaN   NaN
4  2017-05   NaN   NaN
```

**df2**

```
      date  v1  v2  v3  v4
0  2017-01  13   9   7   7
1  2017-02   5   7   5  56
2  2017-03  15   8   6   9
3  2017-04  12  14   8   0
4  2017-05   8   8   4   6
```

Just tried with but I get:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'date')
```

**Output:**

```
      date  v1_x  v2_x  v1_y  v2_y  v3  v4
0  2017-01  12.0   1.0    13     9   7   7
1  2017-02   2.0  13.0     5     7   5  56
2  2017-03  15.0   3.0    15     8   6   9
3  2017-04   NaN   NaN    12    14   8   0
4  2017-05   NaN   NaN     8     8   4   6
```

How can I get the desired output as follows? Thanks.

```
      date  v1  v2  v3  v4
0  2017-01  12   1   7   7
1  2017-02   2  13   5  56
2  2017-03  15   3   6   9
3  2017-04  12  14   8   0
4  2017-05   8   8   4   6
```

Please note there are duplicated values in `date` from `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `fillna`:

```
print(df1.fillna(df2).join(df2[df2.columns.drop(df1.columns)]))
```

Or just:

```
print(df1.fillna(df2).join(df2[['v3', 'v4']]))
```

Both Output:

```
      date    v1    v2  v3  v4
0  2017-01  12.0   1.0   7   7
1  2017-02   2.0  13.0   5  56
2  2017-03  15.0   3.0   6   9
3  2017-04  12.0  14.0   8   0
4  2017-05   8.0   8.0   4   6
```

Answer (score 1):

`combine_first` looks just fine to me, here is an alternative using `concat` and `groupby.first()`:

```
pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).groupby('date').first().reset_index()
```

---

```
      date    v1    v2   v3    v4
0  2017-01  12.0   1.0  7.0   7.0
1  2017-02   2.0  13.0  5.0  56.0
2  2017-03  15.0   3.0  6.0   9.0
3  2017-04  12.0  14.0  8.0   0.0
4  2017-05   8.0   8.0  4.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems works, if you have other solutions. Welcome to share.

```
df1.set_index('date').combine_first(df2.set_index('date'))\
     .reindex(df1.date)\
     .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      date    v1    v2   v3    v4
0  2017-01  12.0   1.0  7.0   7.0
1  2017-02   2.0  13.0  5.0  56.0
2  2017-03  15.0   3.0  6.0   9.0
3  2017-04  12.0  14.0  8.0   0.0
4  2017-05   8.0   8.0  4.0   6.0
```

Comment: Since I have duplicates `date`, so I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. :(